# How to create duplicate rows based on value in a cell

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is a situation where I want to produce duplicate rows for each row present in the table. The number of duplicates is equal to num_rows column in each row.

```
create table test_create_rows(name varchar2(20), num_rows integer);

insert into test_create_rows values('Name1',3);
insert into test_create_rows values('Name2',4);
insert into test_create_rows values('Name3',1);

commit;
```

Expected output:

```
NAME                   NUM_ROWS
-------------------- ----------
Name1                         3
Name1                         3
Name1                         3
Name2                         4
Name2                         4
Name2                         4
Name2                         4
Name3                         1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use `CTE Recursion`

```
WITH CTE(name, num_rows,startnum) AS(
  SELECT name,num_rows,1 startnum
  FROM test_create_rows
  UNION ALL
  SELECT name,num_rows,(startnum + 1) as startnum
  FROM CTE
  WHERE (startnum + 1) <= num_rows
)
SELECT name ,num_rows
FROM CTE
order by name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e989c/12)**:

```
|  NAME | NUM_ROWS |
|-------|----------|
| Name1 |        3 |
| Name1 |        3 |
| Name1 |        3 |
| Name2 |        4 |
| Name2 |        4 |
| Name2 |        4 |
| Name2 |        4 |
| Name3 |        1 |
```

Answer (score 4):

Use cross apply clause together with hierarchical query

```
select x.* 
from test_create_rows t
cross apply (
  select t.NAME, t.NUM_ROWS from dual
  connect by level <= t.num_rows
) x;
```